# Read from Excel and import into Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have an Excel file which has two columns: 1st column(employees) and the second column (abbreviation).

The goal is to fill the initials in AD with the abbreviations oft he employees.

I think the PowerShell script should read the 1st column, check if the 1st column is the same as name in AD, then reads the employee's abbreviation and fill it in AD.

This is my first Powershell script and here is what I tried but of course it does not work:

```
$xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $false
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)

for ($i = 2; $i -le 150) {
   if ($ws.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value2 -ne $null) {
     $Employees = $ws.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value2
     $ abbreviation = $ws.Cells.Item($i, 2).Value2
     write-host " Employees: "$ Employees
     write-host " abbreviation: "$ abbreviation
           }
$i++
}

get-aduser -Filter * -Properties initials | select name, initials

ForEach ($Employees in $name)
{  
      if ($Employees -eq $name)
      {
           #$Initials  -eq $abbreviation 
           Set-ADUser -Initials $ abbreviation
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# This script reads Excel and update the Initials in AD
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory; 
    $PathToXlsx = "C:\test.xlsx"; 

    $xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application";
    $xl.Visible = $false;
    $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($PathToXlsx);
    $ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1);

    for ($i = 2; $i -le 150;$i++) { 
      if ($ws.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value2 -ne $null) {
            $Employee = $ws.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value2;
            $Abbreviation = $ws.Cells.Item($i, 2).Value2;
            Write-Host $Employee;
            Write-Host $Abbreviation;

            try
            {Get-AdUser -Filter 'DisplayName -like $Employee' | Set-ADUser -Initials $Abbreviation; 

            $User = Get-AdUser -Filter 'DisplayName -like $Employee' -Properties 'Initials' | Select Name,Initials | Format-List; 

            Write-Host $User;        
        }
    catch
        {
            Write-Host "Update Failed"
            Write-Host "$Error[0]"
            } 
     }
    }
```

and in case of CSV.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory;
$PathTocsv = "C:\test.csv";

$Users = Import-Csv $PathTocsv -Delimiter ";";

foreach ($user in $Users){
   $Employee = $user.Employee;
   $Abbreviation = $user.Abbreviation;

  Write-Host $Employee;
  Write-Host $Abbreviation;

   Get-AdUser -Filter 'DisplayName -like $Employee' | Set-AdUser -Initials $Abbreviation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to update the initials with the abbreviation field from the file I would save the file as a CSV file initially and then do the following.

You can obviously add in more prompts and error checking along the way.

```
Get-Content test.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Employees, abbreviation |
ForEach-Object {
    Try
    {
        Get-ADUser $_.Employees | Set-ADUser -Initials $_.abbreviation
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Update Failed"
        Write-Host "$Error[0]"

    }
}
```

If there is no header in the file then you can drop the `Select-object -skip 1`

Or simpler

```
$Users = Import-Csv Test.csv

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    Get-ADUser $User.Employees | Set-ADUser -Initials $User.abbreviation
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. did you try it yourself? because the 1st one gives me neither reslut nor error. The 2nd one gives me error: Get-ADUser cannot validate argument on parameter 'identity'.

Comment: Does the file have a header? that is employees and abbreviation?

Comment: If there are no errors then it would have completed, Powershell generally will only tell you if there is an error, if it is successful it will just show nothing... I've used this method and several other methods to update ad. With what your doing I would pull the first initial and initial of the surname and use that to complete the "initials" without a need of a CSV.

Comment: I would check what your copying and pasting also as I've made some typos